# Rails f.select saving integer not string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, select

I have the following line in a rails form for a new submission:

```
<%= f.select :department_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@departments, 'id', 'department') %>
```

I am trying to have it save the department_id as a string, being the actual title of the respective department saved.  Instead I am getting the integer value for the ID of the chosen department.

Comment: What is your column type of `department_id` in database, `integer` or `string`?

Comment: Oh my god I feel stupid.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My bad I didn't realize my database had department_id as an integer.